# class cast exception using SqlResultSetMapping and ConstructorResult

Tags: java, oracle, classcastexception, sqlresultsetmapping

I'm trying to map the results of a NativeQuery to a non-entity pojo, using [`SqlResultSetMapping`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) and [`ConstructorResult`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html)

I'm using this `StreetCity` class, with result mapping:

```
@Data
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "StreetCityResult", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = StreetCity.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "street", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "city", type = String.class) }) })
public class StreetCity {
    public String street;
    public String city;

    public StreetCity(String street, String city) {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

this is the function that performs the NativeQuery

```
public List<StreetCity> retrieveStreetCity(String zipCode, int houseNumber) {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(getLocationQuery(zipCode, houseNumber), "StreetCityResult");
        List<StreetCity> streetCityList = query.getResultList();
        return streetCityList;
    }
```

this is the query that should be excuted

```
public String getLocationQuery(String zipCode, int houseNumber) {
        String query = 
            "select straat.straatnaam as street, plaats.plaatsnaam as city " 
            + " from pcreeks "
            + " left join plaats on plaats.plaatsid = pcreeks.plaatsid "
            + " left join straat on straat.straatid = pcreeks.straatid "
            + " where (...) ";
        return query;
    }
```

but i'm still getting an Exception

```
2017-03-05T16:35:57.736+0100|Warning: javax.ejb.EJBException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to nl.xxx.service.business.locations.entity.StreetCity
```

Edit:
the error comes from the 2nd line of this code:

```
List<StreetCity> streetCityList = storage.retrieveStreetCity(zipCode, houseNumber);
streetCityList.get(0).getStreet();
```

Oracle has the [exact same example in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html), so what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Limit 1 is not valid oracle syntax

Comment: true, i forgot to remove it initialy, but without the limit 1, the result is the same

Comment: this maybe help.'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375565/jpa-2-1-constructorresult-causing-classcastexception'

Comment: i read that post, didn't help
it does talk about "You have to ensure that YourDTO is registered by your persistence provider" but it doesn't say how

Answer (score 1):

found two solutions, in both cases, StreetCity MUST be an @Entity

using @ConstructorResult, it also needs constructors.

solution 1, using @EntityResult instead of @ConstructorResult

```
@Data
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "StreetCityMapping", entities = @EntityResult(entityClass = StreetCity.class, fields = {
        @FieldResult(name = "street", column = "street"), @FieldResult(name = "city", column = "city") }))
public class StreetCity {
    @Id
    public String street;
    public String city;
}
```

solution 2, using @ConstructorResult, with constructors:

```
@Data
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "StreetCityMapping", classes = {
@ConstructorResult(targetClass =
 StreetCity.class, columns = {
 @ColumnResult(name = "street", type = String.class),
 @ColumnResult(name = "city", type = String.class) }) })
public class StreetCity {
    @Id
    public String street;
    public String city;

    public StreetCity() {
    }

    public StreetCity(String street, String city) {
      this.street = street;
      this.city = city;
    }
}
```

no other code changes needed,
i guess solution 1 is the cleanest one